# Is there any free wordpress plugin to showcase client's logo carousel in grayscale effect ?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, web

I want to create one logo carousel to showcase our client companies, I have seen somewhere logos in gray color at the start and once the user hovers on it, it turns to its original logo color?. Anybody, please tell me how can I achieve this effect for WordPress site? with any plugin or external code?

[This kind of effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPQr2.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). _"Questions **asking us to recommend or find** a book, tool, **software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: This plugin may be help you: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tc-logo-slider/ and check the demo

Comment: Hello,  @manishpatel Grayscale effect is not included in free version. I want exactly same effect as I attached in above link (this kind of effect) . By the way thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user this plugin and add below css
"Client Carousel plugin"
img {
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
  filter: grayscale(1); /* Microsoft Edge and Firefox 35+ */
}

/* Disable grayscale on hover */
img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  filter: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Demo Demo. It worked

Comment: I need one more help? required output is coming but last image is not showing in that carousel. there are total 10 logos. I have displayed 5 in each slide. 9 logos are showing properly bu last one is getting cut